# C# Entity Framework, Simplify Select Child Property That Using Same Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 ef model, let's say  `Task()` and `Progress()`

```
public class Task()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
public class Progress()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_Task { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Update { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get data for each task and it's last progress, So i make a ViewModel

```
public class ViewTask()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Last_Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Last_Update { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, this is what i did:

```
var data = _context.Task
    .Select(x => new ViewTask
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Title = x.Title,
        Last_Status = x.Progress.OrderByDescending(y => y.Update)
            .Select(y => y.Status).FirstOrDefault(),
        Last_Update = x.Progress.OrderByDescending(y => y.Update)
            .Select(y => y.Update).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();
```

Is there any better ways so I don't need to repeat `x.Progress...` part? The only code i can think of is something like this:

```
var data = _context.Task
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Title = x.Title,
        Progress = x.Progress.OrderByDescending(y => y.Update).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(x => new ViewTask
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Title = x.Title,
        Last_Status = x.Progress.Status
        Last_Update = x.Progress.Update
    }).ToList();
```

I appriciete any kind of suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaxBy and MinBy methods from [moreLINQ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/) library.

```
var data = _context.Task
.Select(x => new ViewTask
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Title = x.Title,
    Last_Status = x.Progress.MaxBy(y => y.Update).Status,
    Last_Update = x.Progress.MaxBy(y => y.Update).Update
 }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, it's shorter than what i currently use. But how if i also need to use Where(). It's still long and repetitive